# How do I disallow Jenkins admin from modifying through the UI but still allow him to run script console?

Tags: jenkins, authorization, readonly, administrator

My Jenkins instance is fully configured through Jenkins configuration as code plugin.
I set all the authorizations as recommended by:
https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/05/25/read-only-jenkins-announcement/

So I don't want anyone (including admins) to modify parameters in the UI
But I still want to allow admins to run script console.
How can I do that?

Comment: We are also working towards 100% JCasC where supported. We stillnuse scripting dor a lot of tasks. Not clear what that would achieve by restricting. Anything you can do via the UI be manipulated by script. You'd have to also carefully restrict what methods are allowed in scripts and which are not so as to restrict admin config changes.Perhaps you want a monitoring solution for config changes instead?

Comment: thanks. I may go that way. I saw that JobConfigHistory plugin shows all activity on the system

Comment: Yes, jobconfighistory is a lifesaver (so is knowing you can restore feom actual backup)!